# What arguments must I pass to a function to perform an implicit construction of an object?

Tags: c++

My apologies if this is a dupe. I found a number of posts re. preventing implicit conversions, but nothing re. encouraging implicit constructions.

If I have:

```
class Rect
{
public:
    Rect( float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2){};
};
```

and the free function:

```
Rect Scale( const Rect & );
```

why would

```
Rect s = Scale( 137.0f, 68.0f, 235.0f, 156.0f );
```

not do an implicit construction of a `const Rect&` and instead generate this compiler error

```
'Scale' : function does not take 4 arguments
```

Comment: If you're forcing it, then it isn't implicit!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the language does not support this feature. You have to write

```
Rect s = Scale(Rect(137.0f, 68.0f, 235.0f, 156.0f));
```

Answer (score 7):

"Conversions" in C++ are between objects of one type and another type. You have 4 objects (all of type float), so you could have 4 conversions to 4 other types. There's no way to convert (in the C++ sense of the word) 4 objects to one object.

Answer (score 3):

An implicit conversion via constructor takes place **if and only if the constructor takes exactly 1 argument** and isn't declared explicit. In this case it takes 4, thus the result.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about implicitly constructing an object. For instance,

```
class IntWrapper {
    public:
        IntWrapper(int x) { }
};

void DoSomething( const IntWrapper& ) { }

int main() {
    DoSomething(5);
}
```

This works because `IntWrapper`'s constructor takes only one argument. In your case, `Rect` needs 4 arguments, so there's no implicit construction.

Comment: Check out this question on `explicit`, which is the way you forbid this behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean